# Select rows from a table in groups of 3 as a single row

Tags: sql-server

Let's say that I have a table as such:

```
Row       Title       Date
----      -----       ----
1         Title 1     1/1/2018
2         Title 2     1/2/2018
3         Title 3     1/3/2018
4         Title 4     1/4/2018
5         Title 5     1/5/2018
6         Title 6     1/6/2018
```

I would like to select the data into rows that contain three rows per one row (if that makes sense).  For example like this

```
Row1   Title1   Date1      Row2   Title2   Date2      Row3   Title3   Date3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Title 1  1/1/2018   2      Title 2  1/2/2018   3      Title 3  1/3/2018
4      Title 4  1/4/2018   5      Title 5  1/5/2018   6      Title 6  1/6/2018
```

Is this possible?  I've tried using a temp table but was unsuccessful :/

Comment: Easy in a multi-column SSRS report...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
    numbered AS (
        SELECT  Row ,
                Title ,
                Date ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Row) AS RowNumber
        FROM    Table
    )
SELECT  n1.Row AS Row1 ,
        n1.Title AS Title1 ,
        n1.Date AS Date1 ,
        n2.Row AS Row2 ,
        n2.Title AS Title2 ,
        n2.Date AS Date2 ,
        n3.Row AS Row3 ,
        n3.Title AS Title3 ,
        n3.Date AS Date3
FROM    numbered n1
LEFT OUTER JOIN numbered n2 ON n2.RowNumber = n1.RowNumber + 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN numbered n3 ON n3.RowNumber = n1.RowNumber + 2
WHERE   (n1.RowNumber - 1) % 3 = 0
```

Comment: My pleasure.  Good luck!